Make the Ask Wizard's responsive design layout the default
As has been noted before, the Ask Wizard' use of the phrase "What did you try and what were you expecting?" does not seem to be performing its intended role. It tends to elicit vague descriptions of research, such as "I checked Google/ChatGPT but found nothing," rather than useful information like attempted solutions and minimal, reproducible examples.
Some users have proposed alternative texts to fix this. Suggestions include:

EJoshuaS's "Please provide clear steps for others to reproduce and understand your problem - what you tried, what you thought would happen when you did that, and what actually happened instead."

RyanM's "If you have tried to solve this, describe what you tried and what you expected to happen when you tried that."

MrMiyagi's "When asking a debugging question, provide code that follows the guidelines of a minimal, reproducible example."


I like all of these, but as has been noted in the comments of that feature request, this section in the Ask Wizard says many of the same things.

Expand on the problem
Show what you’ve tried, tell us what happened, and why it didn’t meet
your needs.
Not all questions benefit from including code, but if your problem is
better understood with code you’ve written, you should include a
minimal, reproducible example.
Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the
question (and not as images), and format them appropriately.

EJoshuaS suggested in a comment that it's being ignored because it's off to the side of the editor, where it's easy to (dis)miss. As a solution, I propose promoting the sidebar's small-window placement to the default.
Currently, the Ask Wizard's responsive design places the text just above the editor if the browser window is too narrow for a sidebar:



Default placement (sidebar)
Responsive placement (above editor)









Making the second option the default would make the text more visible, which could help users understand what does and doesn't belong in the box.

For this to work, one other change would have to be made. Currently, pressing "Next" after filling out one box will auto-scroll to the next. In a window with the altered layout, this skips past the note entirely. The auto-scroll should stop just before the note instead to ensure it remains visible.

I would regard both as equally easy to miss. You are in a situation where you want to type in the box; you ignore what's outside the box.
How is this instead? (Mock-up)

Expand on the problem
Show what you’ve tried, tell us what happened, and why it didn’t meet your needs.
Not all questions benefit from including code, but if your problem is better understood with code you’ve written, you should include a minimal, reproducible example.
Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and not as images), and format them appropriately.
[Continue]

Then when pressing Continue, you are taken to the editor, with the guidance still visible in case you want to refer to it again. At this point, where exactly it's positioned is probably less important.
